# Issue in the Date which accessing from different Region Framework used is FluentUI with React.js Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date, fluent-ui

I have been trying to implement the code to precent date issue the code is given below. I need a solution for this. This Date Picker is is fluent UI framework which i have been using to select the date in ui.

```
<DatePicker
  placeholder="Enter Date"
  allowTextInput={false}
  id="d"
  label="Start"
  isRequired={true}
  value={condition ? new Date(2023-05-23T00:00:00Z) : null}
  onSelectDate={(value) => this._handleDatePickerRangeInput("d", value, s, "s")}
  formatDate={(date: Date): string => {
    return this.getDateFormat(date.toString());
  }}
/>
```

```
I/P = new Date(2023-05-23T00:00:00Z)
O/P = 22/05/2023
```

Here I am using fluent UI Date picker and where i am facing an issue when i am trying to access the from Different Region Like Mountain Timezone then the date which is appearing is (22/05/2023) it's going 1 day back to the actual date Is there any other solution in which we can prevent the conversion of the date.

I there any other solution in the same fluent ui framework in which we can prevent the conversion.

Comment: 2023-05-23T00:00:00Z is UTC (indicated by the trailing Z). American Mountain Standard Time is 7 hours earlier, so the equivalent is 2023-05-22T17:00:00-07:00, i.e. 5 pm on the day prior.

Comment: @RobG Is There any way in which we can avoid the conversion if the user from two different location are trying to access the same project in which date is already submitted as 23/05/2023 & this date should be visible to both the user instead of getting converted?